# prepend a div relative to the parent div

Tags: jquery, prepend

I am using an RSS Feed and want to append the Date into the description, obviously there are more than one date and description.

How can I prepend so that the dates are relative to the parent?

I have tried answers on here but can't get them to work, beginner at JQuery.

So far I have

```
$('.RSSItem').each (function() { 
$('.Description').prepend($('.PubDate') ); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="RSSItem">
<div class="Description">
<div class="PubDate">Monday, 14 January 2013</div>
</div>
```

Each date needs to be moved into the Description, problem I am having is that all the dates for each RSSItem are showing for each RSSItem, I just want the one relevant to the RSSItem.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: please posr your HTML codes too..

Comment: You have `.RSSItem`s that each one contains a `.Description` and `.PubDate`. So you want to prepend all `.PubDate` in the `.Description`?

Comment: Hi There I have just updated question with html,hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Your code miss a closing div tag.. Where does it should go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there may be multiple RSSItems, and multiple descriptions, and assuming that the PubDates are contained right underneath the RSSItems in your source (there seems to be a closing div missing), I'd suggest that you loop through each of the RSSItems and descriptions:

```
$('.RSSItem').each (function() {
    var $pubDate = $(this).find(".PubDate");
    $(this).find(".Description").each(function() {
        $(this).prepend($pubDate);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.RSSItem').each (function() { 
$('.Description', this).prepend($('.PubDate') ); 
});
```

$('.Description') will return all the Description nodes found in the page.  $('.Description', this) will return only the nodes found within corresponding $('.RSSItem')

Comment: In this case, I suppose `$('.PubDate')` should be replaced by `$('.PubDate', this)` no ?

Comment: I think PubDate will not be there initially. And the question is about prepending it to all Description. No?

Comment: Don't know, its message is not clear. But in its HTML example, we can see that the `.pubdate` element is inside the .rssitem, alongside to .description